# Beamer nested lists: do not decrease the font size

Tags: beamer, lists, fontsize, itemize

Simple problem: I would like the nested lists to keep the standard font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Top level
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Lower level (how to make it implicitly normal size?)
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you mean something like: `\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}`?

Comment: @dcmst I don't mean _something like_ that. I mean _exactly_ that. So please make it an answer. Well, there's a second option that would make the symbol larger too. If you had an answer for that too, it would be nice and complete ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize} %to set the body size
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\normalsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}  %to set the symbol size

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Top level
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Lower level (how to make it implicitly normal size?)
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is also the `itemize subitem` template, but as explained the manual (12.1) it ignores the font specs, so we need to re-set the template and specify the size there.

I'm not completely sure you want the symbol in `normalsize` because that would be bigger than the symbol used for first level items, which is in `scriptsize` size.